# How does the Zope Component Architecture (ZCA) relate to Service Component Architecture (SCA)?

Tags: architecture, python, soa

I'm very new to the principle of Service Component Architecture and Zope in general, but the more I look, the more ZCA seems to be a good solution for a certain class of problems I often encounter.

I have read through most (if not all) of the `zope.interface` and `zope.component` tutorials, and I'm left with the feeling that I understand the library's constructs and terminology (e.g. I understand how interfaces relate to adapters), but not how the framework, on the whole, is intended to be used.

What's more, the ZCA seems to be built around the principle of *Service Component Architecture*, but I don't understand how to go about employing Zope tools to implement SCA-compliant software.

## My questions are as follows:

1. To what extend does ZCA want me to adhere to "the SCA way of doing things"?
2. What are the fundamental assumptions/concepts of SCA I need to bear in mind? (please see below for information on what I think I understand)
3. What is the relationship between the Zope component registry and importing things from submodules?  Is the former meant as a replacement for the latter in most circumstances?
4. I think I have a problem that would benefit from the ZCA.  What are the usual features of a problem that make the ZCA the correct answer?

## Supplementary Information:

#### Familiarity with Zope Constructs

I have read through the [Comprehensive Guide to Zope Component Architecture](http://muthukadan.net/docs/zca.html), but I'm left with a feeling similar to when I learned my first programming language:  I know the names of things and what they do, but I don't understand how to orchestrate all the various pieces into a useful *thing*.

By analogy, a python newbie might know how to define a function and make a loop, but he doesn't know how to make a *program*.

I read through the above guide's case study, but I frankly didn't find it very elucidating.  I see how ZCA helps in that particular context, **but I'm struggling to generalize.**

#### Familiarity with Software Component Architecture

I only have a *very* superficial understanding of SCA, most of which stems from the Wikipedia articles on SCA and Service Oriented Architecture, along with [this article](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/) from my (distant) past life as an indie game developer.

Perhaps I'm missing something crucial, here?  I've been trying to reason in terms of implementing the ideas in the "Cowboy Programming" article above (the gamedev one) with ZCA, but maybe I'm only confusing myself?

#### A Solution in Search of  Problem?

I don't want my fellow stackexchangers to think that I'm hell-bent on using ZCA for my next project.  I'm not.  I'm simply struggling to understand The Right Way<sup>TM</sup> of using ZCA.

Again, I'm unable to:

- generalise from the examples provided in the documentation
- imagine the high-level structure and organisation of a ZCA code base.

Comment: I've never used the term SCA in context of the ZCA; a quick glance at the WP description tells me SCA is far higher level (and includes support for the components to be implemented in different languages).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, this surprises me.  ZCA seems to have a notion of "services" (in the SCA sense) and is all about making highly-independent things talk to each other through strictly-defined interfaces.  Is there a "Zope paradigm" of any sort?  Could you address questions 3 and 4?  Thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I would also like to point out that the official Zope site seems to endorse "component architecture" (wiki.zope.org/zope3/ComponentArchitectureOverview) although perhaps this is distinct from SCA?  wiki.zope.org/zope3/ComponentArchitectureOverview

Comment: I'm trying to work out a clear way of addressing your question; I think it is mostly a case of giving you a more concrete example. Have you looked at how Plone and Pyramid use the ZCA?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Yes, my question is a bit difficult to answer since it amounts to "what am I not understanding?" :)  I haven't looked at Plone and Pyramid, but I am familiar with it's use in the Twisted project.  I'll look at Plone/Pyramid though, thanks!

Comment: Plone is a huge project that's built on top of Zope and heavily relies on the ZCA. Pyramid hides their use of the ZCA somewhat; configurations mostly happen transparently.

Comment: The "Comprehensive Guide to Zope Architecture" says that *The ZCA is all about using Python objects effectively. Components are reusable objects with introspectable interfaces. An interface is an object that describes how you work with a particular component. In other words, component provides an interface implemented in a class, or any other callable object. It doesn't matter how the component is implemented, the important part is that it comply with its interface contracts...*

Comment: *...Using ZCA, you can spread the complexity of systems over multiple cooperating components. It helps you to create two basic kinds of components: adapter and utility.* -- Can you explain how your understanding differs from this, or how this description is inadequate to fully explain ZCA?

Comment: Also, when I encounter a framework that I don't fully understand, I know that the only way that I'm going to "get" the framework is to actually use it in a software project, in a code writing context.  Have you taken the time to do this?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'm reasonably familiar with Zope in the context of Twisted.  I suppose my question can be rephrased as follows:  Is there a common pattern for making use of registered components and utilities?  I'm not sure component/utility registration fundamentally differs from using `getattr` on a submodule, for instance, and I can't even fathom why/how factories necessary or somehow more useful than class `__init__` functions and/or metaclasses.  The component-registration part of Zope strikes me as reinventing the (module) wheel.

Comment: There are several such patterns.  See [Component-Based Software Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering) for a description of some of them.  See also [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  All that's really required is an Interface and registration mechanism.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, ah okay this seems to be what I was looking for, rather than SOA!  Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I don't use Plone on client projects, but I found studying how Plone uses the ZCA to be very valuable in learning how to use the ZCA effectively. Plone viewlets as multi-adapters really made it click for me.